# How to customize vim editor using someone else's customization?

Tags: vim, vimrc

I downloaded a file that would help me customize my vim editor [here in the section on "Customizing Vim"](https://missing.csail.mit.edu/2020/editors/). I now have the file in `/home/double_toned` as vimrc. 
Now when I type vim in the command line, I do not get any output of customization. Why is this? What else do I need to do?

Also, how can I open a random txt file on vim editor using the above customization in vim?

Output of `vim --version`

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jun 06 2019 17:31:41)
Included patches: 1-1453
```

Comment: Can you please add the output of `vim --version` to your question?

Comment: @SimonSudler ,  I have added the output of vim --version.

Comment: okay. Can you also add the lines of our `$HOME/.vimrc` that are not working?

Comment: @SimonSudler  I found that ```vim ~/.vimrc``` will run the text file that customizes vim. Indeed, this file has the required customization but this does not help me, how do I open the other files that I have on vim with customization? Right now, if I use ```vim [code file]``` I do not get any error but the code file is opened in vim without customization.

Comment: Vim will always load the `~/.vimrc` file. So I assume, that there is some bug in your configuration file.Usually Vim complaints about syntax errors in the `.vimrc`. Die you see any error messages (in vim enter `:messages`)

Comment: @SimonSudler when I enter the command ```vim ~/.vimrc``` , I do get the following warning ```Swap file "~/.vimrc.swp" already exists!``` Once I choose to override this and enter ```:messages```, I get the following error: ```E325: ATTENTION ~/.vimrc" 80L, 3254C```

Answer (score 0):

open vim editor by typing `vim` in the terminal
Once in vim, type `:so <name of file with customization>` In my case, the file was named vimrc so, my input was 
`:so vimrc`
and you get all the customization in the vim file you are in.

Note: Got this info from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2VpEIQKEdc)